# How to proxy part of a PHP website from GitHub?

Tags: php, github, web, proxy

We have a website containing a page http://www.openehr.org/downloads/modellingtools whose link "Download and Help Pages" in the first table row just goes to more PHP content - the documentation of a tool, in the same visual style as the main website, including top panel, menu and bottom menu.

Ideally this sub-tree of pages for the tool would live in the GitHub repo for that tool (rather than being directly part of the website), and the main website would proxy the content from GitHub - that way we would achieve two goals:

1. tool doc is maintained by those who work on the tool
2. but it is visually integrated into the central website.

I've messed around with various Apache proxy & rewrite rules on the main site server to do this, but no luck so far. I can't be the only one who wants to do this, so hopefully there is a known strategy out there.

Comment: Would using github pages ( http://pages.github.com/ ) and a subdomain of your site work eg mytool.mysite.com

Comment: I wouldn't read them live from Github. Instead I'd have a local folder containing a local git repo with the upstream pointing at the GH repo, and a cron that does a `git pull` periodically.

Comment: @halfer - you mean it would be a Git module within the main website Git repo? On the webserver, we could do a cron'd pull - does a pull cause pulls to occur for sub-component git repos? Actually this wouldn't work anyway, because we only want the doc subtree from the other repo, not the whole thing.

Comment: A `git pull` doesn't automatically update submodules, no - you need to follow it up with a `git submodule update` for that. Do look into the docs for `git` - you may well just be able to pull the section you want. But, even if you can't, would it be so bad to have the whole repo on your server? How big is it, in MB?

Comment: Well the repo isn't that big I guess, but it just seems dumb to have to pull 20Mb software repo to get 2Mb of doc files... Nevertheless, I will investigate this approach, it might be the only practical one. Thanks for the idea. If I get anything definitive working, I'll post an answer.